# Training variable number of neural networks in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a piece of code that trains a different number of neural networks depending on the problem instance. I am new to tensorflow graph execution and I am not sure what the best way is to do this. Currently, I have code that looks like this:

```
@tf.function
def train_step(nn_list, batch, optimizer):
  with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    loss = 0
    for nn in nn_list:
      out = nn(batch, training=True)
      loss += some_function(out)
  
  trainable_variables = []
  gradients = []
  for nn in nn_list:
    trainable_variables += nn.trainable_variables
    gradients += tape.gradient(loss, nn.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_variables))
```

I have a few questions:
Is the for loop okay to run forward pass on the list of neural networks? Does it affect graph optimization?
Is there a better way than list append to collect trainable_variables and gradients?